# Using jQuery.ajaxSetup to define beforeSend and alter data sent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Basically, I want to create a generic `beforeSend` function that alters the data each `jQuery.ajax` method sends, so I can add a custom variable (for tracking) to each request without knowing the order of the requests sent.

For example, say I wanted to count how many requests were sent by a particular user on a particular page.

Something like this:

```
var numRequests = 0;

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, Obj){
      console.log(arguments);
      dataToBeSent.numRequests = ++numRequests;
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'test.js',
    data: {testVar:1,testVar:"2",testVar:{3:1}},
    complete: function(){
      console.log('complete');
    }
});
```

Is this possible?

I have a basic JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kY5UP/

Comment: do you want to set a parameter or a request header

Comment: Parameter ideally (I think). What's the difference? Are request headers easy enough to retrieve (using PHP) and settable in a generic sense?

Comment: I think manipulation of data in beforeSend might be little difficult... but if you can use PHP to read request headers then you can use `jqXHR.setRequestHeader('numRequests', ++numRequests)`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass extra data like this:

```
var numRequests = 0;

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, Obj){
      console.log(Obj.data);
      //this code line adds extra parameter to the request
      Obj.data = $.extend(Obj.data, {numRequests: ++numRequests});
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'test.js',
    data: {testVar:1,testVar:"2",testVar:{3:1}},
    complete: function(){
      console.log('complete');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes..You can do this:

```
var numRequests = 0;

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, Obj){
      console.log(Obj.data);
      Obj.data.numRequests = ++numRequests;
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'test.js',
    data: {testVar:1,testVar:"2",testVar:{3:1}},
    complete: function(){
      console.log('complete');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure? When I `console.log(Obj.data)` I get `undefined`